# Пытаюсь сделать конвертер шрифтов из плагинов Gulp, но не работает скрипт

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

gulpfile.js

```
const {src, dest, parallel, series } = require('gulp');
const ttf2woff2 = require('gulp-ttf2woff2');
const fonter = require('gulp-fonter');

function convert() {
  return src('fonts/*.ttf')
    .pipe(fonter({
        subset: [66,67,68, 69, 70, 71],
        formats: ['woff', 'ttf']
      }))
     .pipe(ttf2woff2())
     .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
}
exports.default = convert;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "gulp-font-converter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "font-converter ttf to woff, woff2",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "gulp"
  },
  "author": "AlexDream",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
        "gulp-cli": "^2.3.0"
    },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-fonter": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-ttf2woff2": "^4.0.1"
  }
}
```

В терминале

```
$ npm run start

> gulp-font-converter@1.0.0 start
> gulp

[13:53:46] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\gulp-font-converter\gulpfile.js
[13:53:46] Starting 'default'...
[13:53:46] 'default' errored after 22 ms
[13:53:46] ReferenceError: gulp is not defined
    at convert2 (C:\Users\AlexD\Desktop\gulp-font-converter\gulpfile.js:17:9)
    at taskWrapper (C:\Users\AlexD\Desktop\gulp-font-converter\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:13:15)
    at bound (node:domain:421:15)
    at runBound (node:domain:432:12)
    at asyncRunner (C:\Users\AlexD\Desktop\gulp-font-converter\node_modules\async-done\index.js:55:18)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас элементарная ошибка. Вы распарсили модуль, а в конце функции `convert()` обращаетесь к функции `dest()` через точку.
Рабочий код:

```js
const {src, dest, parallel, series } = require('gulp');
const ttf2woff2 = require('gulp-ttf2woff2');
const fonter = require('gulp-fonter');

function convert() {
  return src('fonts/*.ttf')
    .pipe(fonter({
        subset: [66,67,68, 69, 70, 71],
        formats: ['woff', 'ttf']
      }))
     .pipe(ttf2woff2())
     .pipe(dest('./dist'));
}
exports.default = convert;
```

Comment: Вот спасибо вам добрый человек, в очках сижу и не заметил.

Comment: Попробовал воспользоваться предложеным кодом для проекта, и оно у меня не завелось. Там у разработчиков есть какие-то пакеты  - `gulp-fonter-2` но тоже не сработало. Вам это правило помогло ?  Ищу что-то похожее но для конвертирование в woff2

Comment: да, исправил и заработало

Comment: Gulp и gulp-cli глобально тоже должен быть установлен